# Redirecting from old site to new with page links

Tags: .htaccess

I have two websites:

1. olddomain.org
2. newdomain.com

I need to edit .htaccess file on olddomain.org to redirect ALL traffic from that site to the newdomain.com

However, I would like a few rules to send requests from old specific pages to new site's pages, that match the content, but not the page names, so I'll need to add rules for those pages manually, or if there's a way to use some sort of regex matching - even better. If there's no match - redirect to new domain.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
# Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 404.php

# 301 Redirect URLs
Redirect 301 /tools/tool-1.htm https://www.newdomain.com/tool-1
Redirect 301 /documents/tool-article.doc https://www.newdomain.com/tool-2
```

When tested, the first redirect to tool-1 works great, however, the second link, possibly because it was to a .doc document redirects to new site's 404 page.

How can I fix this?

Comment: We cannot really answer to this. The rule you implemented loos fine, so most likely this is an issue with the resource in the new system. Tripple check if `/tool-2` _really_ exists, can be requested. Also check the http server's error log file in the new system. And make sure there are actually is a redirection performed by looking into your browser's development console.

Comment: @arkascha Hmm, I thought I tested but you could be right. It may not be a file type issue. Is there a way to add a 301 redirect just to new domain if none other page specific matches are made? Thanks

Comment: Sure, you simply add a fallback redirection at the end, _below_ all specific redirections. I generally prefer the rewriting module for that, it offers far more flexibility.

Comment: I need it to be 301 as well. Will it be something like: Redirect 301 /(*) https://www.newdomain.com

Comment: The rewriting module is very well able to send 301 redirections. Take a look at the examples in the documentation.

Comment: `Redirect 301 /(*)` - you don't need to do any such kind of capturing (`(*)`) with the `Redirect` directive, since it works based on path _prefixes_ only. Any parts of the path after what you have matched against, will automatically get appended to the target URL. (Note what the docs have to say about complete path segments though.)

Comment: @04FS I will be adding more redirect rules to point from existing OLD domain page links to new domain pages, but I do also want to redirect all links that don't have new domain page replacement just to the new domain. Are you saying that after my # 301 Redirect URLs I can just add something like this: Redirect 301 / https://www.newdomain.com/